Manga where the male MC befriends a female elf girl and a black merchant fairy who's one of four demon generals
The male MC befriends a female elf girl. I don't really remember much, but he also befriends a black merchant fairy who is actually one of the four demon generals.
He goes diving to get some rare water from a big tree because one of his friends gets poisoned and the water is needed for the antidote. The fairy questions what his motives are because he got summoned to the other world and he's supposed to kill the demon lord, but he just tells him he needs that water, and the fairy agrees to give it to him. Later, the black fairy introduces them to the socially awkward young demon lord who never goes outside.
Later, the demon lord goes to the grave of his parents where there is a recorded message for him, and he finally decides to be the real demon lord. But for that, he needs to prove that he's worthy, and the MC fights in some duels for him.
That's all, sorry.

Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Do you remember when you read it?

This is Kanzen Kaihi Healer no Kiseki.

A college student, Sakurai Hiroki was summoned to another world to defeat the Demon Lord. And since he got “Priest” job, his starting Recovery Stat was more than enough to heal any wounds, so he dumped all of his Stat Points to Evasion. In other words, he’s aiming for an Evasion Healer who will never get hits by enemy attacks. But unfortunately, people on that world couldn’t understand his ideal! The King got angry against him and labelled him as useless almost immediately! And thus, the story of how Hiroki become an odd Healer who can even avoid Dungeon Boss’ attack with ease has started!!

The elf girl is his first companion and shows up in the first few chapters. The fairy merchant appears occasionally early on but isn't a companion; there's also no indication she's working for the demon lord.
I forget the exact details, but the "sick friend" would be the hero who was also summoned at the same time; he gets cursed and Hiroko gathers items to try to save him.
The scenes with the demon lord start around chapter 40; Hiroko and Lusha, along with the shop fairy, go to visit the recluse demon lord. They play some games, eat together, and have a small competition where Hiroko has to dodge the demon lord's overwhelmingly strong magic.
The specific scene with the grave is at the end of chapter 44 and the beginning of chapter 45.

Although if I'm not misreading the next few pages, it's not a pre-recorded message, it's just another guy standing up in the trees and talking, then "If your father was alive that's what he would've said".
